# How to do Gradient Normalization using Tensorflow LazyAdamOptimizer in functional Keras Model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent

I am using a bidirectional RNN in Keras and need to use Tensoflows LazyAdamOptimizer. I need to do Gradient Normalization. How can I implement gradient normalization with tensorflows LazyAdamOptimizer and than use the functional keras model further on?

I am training a unsupervised RNN to predict a input sequence of lenght 10. The Problem is, that i am using a keras functional model. Because of the sparsity of the embedding layer i need to use Tensorflows LazyAdamOptimizer, which is not a default optimizer in keras. When using a default keras optimizer i can do gradient normalization just by setting the argument 'clipnorm=1' in the optimizer function. Because i am using LazyAdam i need to do this with tensorflow and than pass it back to my keras model, but i can't get the code going.

```
#model architecture
model_input = Input(shape=(seq_len, ))
embedding_a = Embedding(len(port_fwd_dict), 50, input_length=seq_len, mask_zero=True)(model_input)
lstm_a = Bidirectional(GRU(25, return_sequences=True,implementation=2, reset_after=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'), merge_mode="concat (embedding_a)
dropout_a = Dropout(0.2)(lstm_a)
lstm_b = Bidirectional(GRU(25, return_sequences=False, activation="relu", implementation=2, reset_after=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'), merge_mode="concat")(dropout_a)
dropout_b = Dropout(0.2)(lstm_b)
dense_layer = Dense(100, activation="linear")(dropout_b)
dropout_c = Dropout(0.2)(dense_layer)
model_output = Dense(len(port_fwd_dict)-1, activation="softmax(dropout_c)

# trying to implement gradient normalization
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.LazyAdamOptimizer()
optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(optimizer, 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(categorical_crossentropy(model_input, model_output))
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.train.get_global_step())

model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)

model.compile(optimizer=train_op, loss='categorical_crossentropie', metrics = [ 'categorical_accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split, class_weight = 'auto')
```

> Blockquote

I get the following Error: NameError: name 'categorical_crossentropy' is not defined

But even if this error is solved, i do not know if this code will work. Because I need to use  the keras function model.compile and in this function there need to be a loss specified. but when i do this in the tensorflow part above, it is not working.
I need a way to do gradient normalization and use my normal keras functional model?!

Comment: `from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy` --- Did you try to use `optimizer = keras.optimizers.TFOptimizer(tf.contrib.opt.LazyAdamOptimizer(), clipnorm=1)`?

Comment: @DanielMöller. unfortunatly this throws another error : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clipnorm'. the official keras docs says:from keras import optimizers

# All parameter gradients will be clipped to
# a maximum norm of 1.
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipnorm=1.)

Comment: @DanielMöller do you know any other way to use lazy adam optimizer, do gradient normalization and pass this in the model.compile() function?

Comment: But `clipnorm` is a parameter from the base `Optimizer` class, not from `SGD`. The documentation also says every keras optimizer has this. Just to be sure, you added `clipnorm` **outside** of the `LayzAdamOptimizer()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try my implement of lazy optimizer:
https://github.com/bojone/keras_lazyoptimizer

It is a pure keras implement, wrapping a existing optimizer to be a lazy version.